# Stop Solver after it has reached a certain number of dps

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to stop solver after it has found a solution to 2 dps and move on to the next solve in the loop?

For example after 3 trials the result may be 3.2454, trial 4 will be 3.2458 and so on until it finds the exact solution. The thing is I only care about the solution 3.24 and any further precision will have no material impact on my calculations and the further trials just slow the whole thing down with no real gain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution:

```
SolverOptions Precision:=0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to change your sheet so that the "answer" is 100x the actual answer and then limit Solver to an integer only answer. You should be able to do this by adding the "answer" as a constraint rule - see the picture where solver changes $B$3 subject to keeping it an integer.

[image]

Comment: nice idea. how do i limit solver to an integer only answer?

Comment: I've added text and picture to my answer